# Filtering requested parameters for log in with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a "rut" identificator for a supplier model.

The real rut is formatted by dots and hyphens.

A sample rut would be: 34.546.555-2

In my DB I store the plain suppliers rut, as for the example above: 34546552

My question is, how can I filter the requested params on the log-in so devise reads the plain "rut"?

I've tried with customizing the devise controllers and adding a before_filter which filters the params hash and tweaking the sign_in_params with no success. When I debug the following line on the create action of the Devise sessions controller:

```
warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
```

I receive the following:

```
!! #<ArgumentError: uncaught throw :warden>
```

Which might be causing the log in unsuccesfull.

Comment: Can you store it in the database as a string?

Comment: @StefanLance I could, but I already implemented it this way and I prefer to store it as an integer. Somehow it feels that is a better way than using the hyphens and dots version.